# Is there a way to make the Chrome DevTools color picker larger?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, web-inspector

While in Chrome DevTools (f12) one can click a color swatch next to the hex value of a css rule. This brings up a color chooser with a sweet pixel zoom-picker ability. That's all good, but when *not* using the pixel picker it's hard to nail a specific color. This is because the color picker is small, therefore the sliders/chooser are too sensitive. It's very hard to get a specific hue for example, and if you have had any sort of coffee making the mousing hand shake, it's hilariously [almost] impossible to let go at an exact "pixel" on the slider.

I see [DevTools has extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) where one can add panels/panes, but I'm not seeing if it's possible to manipulate the actual DevTools DOM, nor [if so] how to inspect the inspector while the color picker is init.

How would I go about this? Is there a way to increase the size of the colorpicker by say, about double? A cheesy blurry CSS scale is fine, nothing fancy needed. This would allow useable slider targeting. Sorry if this is off topic in stackoverflow, its focal towards coding up an extension/solution, not how to use DevTools (ie, webapps.stackexchange).

Comment: The color picker isn't meant to get you the very specific color you want, but a close-enough one to see what it would look like. If you know the color you want, type it in.

Comment: @Garbee The colorpicker is indeed meant to get you the specific color you want, otherwise all the colors wouldn't be available, right.

Comment: "but a close-enough one to see what it would look like. If you know the color you want, type it in." It needs to have them all available simply to allow you to get close. If you can get exact great, but the vast majority of DevTools use, close is good enough.

Comment: @Garbee Yes procure a color....from another tiny colorpicker, haha ;) Really I don't use anything besides DevTools and an editor. I can make everything with those. There is no need to use Illustrator or other workflows for making views/apps nowadays....just gets in the way. The colorpickers (and extensions) aren't really any better anyways, and the extra workflow step + time + bloat doesn't really attribute anything to development. So if this DevTools one was bigger, it would work fine, right....unless you actually have a case for how it is besides "it's supposed to be small and inaccurate"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just zooming on your DevTools window? `Ctrl` and `+` on Windows / Linux, `Cmd` and `+` on Mac.

Small:

[image]

Big:

[image]

Comment: Use `Ctrl`+`0` to reset to default size here for anyone wondering how after zooming.

Answer (score 3):

The color picker used in Chrome DevTools is an implementation of [Spectrum](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/), which was added into Web Inspector for WebKit, and subsequently Blink-based browsers back in 2013. There are currently no API's that expose the color picker to [Chrome Extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools).

You have a couple of options I can think off:

1. [Log an issue here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) with some details and screenshots, and come up with a strong case for changes the sizing of the picker. I think it is a good idea.
2. Download a copy of the DevTools web app locally and hook it up to a Chrome instance, using the Remote Debugging Protocol. See [Hacking Chrome DevTools](https://medium.com/@aslushnikov/hacking-chrome-devtools-8c8896f5cef3#.qkdqygoqm) for the specific instructions.

The second option is a cool way to customise DevTools locally, but it's not a long term solution, as you would have to get latest code regularly to maintain compatibility with the back-end.

**Update:** The 3rd option I stupidly missed, is simply zooming in, as per Kayce's answer, that I just saw just as I posted this reply. On a Mac, you can also use <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> to zoom the whole window. Omitting the <kbd>Alt</kbd> zooms just the current window.

Comment: Good ideas, thanks. I wasn't sure which answer to accept, wish i could pick 2. The zoom, albeit not optimal, works for now. I will log an issue when i get time and post a link to it here though.